# SQL query returning null rather than 1 or 0

Tags: sql, printing

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[permissions] WHERE [dbo].[permissions].[fk_sites_recid] = {0})
 PRINT 1 ELSE PRINT 0
```

I want to know if a particular record exists in a table and saw a query similar to the above which should return a 0 or a 1.

It's worked in the past for me, but not now.

If I run it in sql management studio, it returns a 1 or 0 as expected, but running it from my c# application it's returning null whether or not there exists an fk_sites_recid with that value. I've tried the same query with both a datareader and scalar result returned as null. Can anybody think if there's something odd going on somewhere that's causing this?
I have my connection and transaction open during the whole of the lifetime of a migration of data, the transaction (I think) is the only thing that's different between running it in sql management studio and via my .net app.

```
      if (found)
      {
        // Does it already exist? if so, don't re-add
        string sql = string.Format(@"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[permissions]
          WHERE [dbo].[permissions].[fk_sites_recid] = {0})
          PRINT 1 ELSE PRINT 0", destRow.fk_Sites_RecID);
        using (var command = GetCommand(sql))
        {
          object o = command.ExecuteScalar(); // <- returns null here
          if (o.ToString() != "0")
            continue;
        }  
        using (var command = GetCommand(sql))
        {
          using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
            while (reader.Read()) // <- reader doesn't read anything here
            {
              object o = reader[0];

            }
          }
        }                                       
      }


protected SqlCommand GetCommand(string sql)
{
  var result = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection, Transaction);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `PRINT`, it returns a custom message to the client, but it does not return data to your data reader. Rather than using `PRINT`, you should use `SELECT`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[permissions] WHERE [dbo].[permissions].[fk_sites_recid] = {0})
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as SomeField
```

Consider using a named parameter for `fk_Sites_RecID`. Even though it does not look like you are open to SQL injection attack in this particular instance, it is a good idea to avoid generating parameters dynamically as a matter of following best practices.